# Display a div when another div reaches the exact number

Tags: javascript

```
 <header class="wrap">
            <h1>Snake</h1>
            <p class="score">Score: <span id="score_value">0</span></p>
        </header>
        <canvas class="wrap" id="snake" width="320" height="320" tabindex="1"></canvas>

        <!-- Game Over Screen -->
        <div id="gameover">
            <h2>Game Over</h2>
            <p>press <span style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000">space</span> to begin a</p>
            <a id="newgame_gameover">new game</a>
            <a id="setting_gameover">settings</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Setting screen -->
        <div id="setting">
            <h2>Settings</h2>

            <a id="newgame_setting">new game</a>

            <p>Speed:
                <input id="speed1" type="radio" name="speed" value="120" checked/>
                <label for="speed1">Slow</label>
                <input id="speed2" type="radio" name="speed" value="75"/>
                <label for="speed2">Normal</label>
                <input id="speed3" type="radio" name="speed" value="35"/>
                <label for="speed3">Fast</label>
            </p>

            <p>Wall:
                <input id="wallon" type="radio" name="wall" value="1" checked/>
                <label for="wallon">On</label>
                <input id="walloff" type="radio" name="wall" value="0"/>
                <label for="walloff">Off</label>
            </p>

        </div>

        <!-- Main Menu Screen -->
        <div id="menu">
            <h2>Snake</h2>

            <a id="newgame_menu">new game</a>
            <a id="setting_menu">settings</a>
        </div>

        <div id="promotional-code" >RETRO50</div>
</div>


<script>

            (function(){  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Canvas & Context
var canvas;
var ctx;

// Snake
var snake;
var snake_dir;
 var snake_next_dir;
var snake_speed;

// Food
var food = {x: 0, y: 0};

// Score
var score;

// Wall
var wall;

// HTML Elements
var screen_snake;
var screen_menu;
var screen_setting;
var screen_gameover;
var button_newgame_menu;
var button_newgame_setting;
var button_newgame_gameover;
var button_setting_menu;
var button_setting_gameover;
var ele_score;
var speed_setting;
var wall_setting;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var activeDot = function(x, y){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var changeDir = function(key){

    if(key == 38 && snake_dir != 2){
        snake_next_dir = 0;
    }else{

    if (key == 39 && snake_dir != 3){
        snake_next_dir = 1;
    }else{

    if (key == 40 && snake_dir != 0){
        snake_next_dir = 2;
    }else{

    if(key == 37 && snake_dir != 1){
        snake_next_dir = 3;
    } } } }

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var addFood = function(){
    food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.width / 10) - 1));
    food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((canvas.height / 10) - 1));
    for(var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
        if(checkBlock(food.x, food.y, snake[i].x, snake[i].y)){
            addFood();
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var checkBlock = function(x, y, _x, _y){
    return (x == _x && y == _y) ? true : false;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var altScore = function(score_val){
    ele_score.innerHTML = String(score_val);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var mainLoop = function(){

        var _x = snake[0].x;
        var _y = snake[0].y;
        snake_dir = snake_next_dir;

        // 0 - Up, 1 - Right, 2 - Down, 3 - Left
        switch(snake_dir){
            case 0: _y--; break;
            case 1: _x++; break;
            case 2: _y++; break;
            case 3: _x--; break;
        }

        snake.pop();
        snake.unshift({x: _x, y: _y});


    // --------------------

    // Wall

        if(wall == 1){
        // On
            if (snake[0].x < 0 || snake[0].x == canvas.width / 10 || snake[0].y < 0 || snake[0].y == canvas.height / 10){
                showScreen(3);
                return;
            }
        }else{
        // Off
            for(var i = 0, x = snake.length; i < x; i++){
                if(snake[i].x < 0){
                    snake[i].x = snake[i].x + (canvas.width / 10);
                }
                if(snake[i].x == canvas.width / 10){
                    snake[i].x = snake[i].x - (canvas.width / 10);
                }
                if(snake[i].y < 0){
                    snake[i].y = snake[i].y + (canvas.height / 10);
                }
                if(snake[i].y == canvas.height / 10){
                    snake[i].y = snake[i].y - (canvas.height / 10);
                }
            }
        }

    // --------------------

    // Autophagy death
        for(var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++){
            if (snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y){
                showScreen(3);
                return;
            }
        }

    // --------------------

  // Eat Food
        if(checkBlock(snake[0].x, snake[0].y, food.x, food.y)){
            snake[snake.length] = {x: snake[0].x, y: snake[0].y};
            score += 1;
            altScore(score);
            addFood();
            activeDot(food.x, food.y);
        }

    // --------------------

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // --------------------

        for(var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++){
            activeDot(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
        }

    // --------------------

        activeDot(food.x, food.y);

    // Debug
    //document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = snake_dir + " " + snake_next_dir + " " + snake[0].x + " " + snake[0].y;      

        setTimeout(mainLoop, snake_speed);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var newGame = function(){

    showScreen(0);
    screen_snake.focus();

    snake = [];
    for(var i = 4; i >= 0; i--){
        snake.push({x: i, y: 15});
    }

    snake_next_dir = 1;

    score = 0;
    altScore(score);

    addFood();

    canvas.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        changeDir(evt.keyCode);
    }
    mainLoop();

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Change the snake speed...
// 150 = slow
// 100 = normal
// 50 = fast
var setSnakeSpeed = function(speed_value){
    snake_speed = speed_value;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var setWall = function(wall_value){
    wall = wall_value;
    if(wall == 0){screen_snake.style.borderColor = "#606060";}
    if(wall == 1){screen_snake.style.borderColor = "#FFFFFF";}
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// 0 for the game
// 1 for the main menu
// 2 for the settings screen
// 3 for the game over screen
var showScreen = function(screen_opt){
    switch(screen_opt){

        case 0:  screen_snake.style.display = "block";
                 screen_menu.style.display = "none";
                 screen_setting.style.display = "none";
                 screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
                 break;

        case 1:  screen_snake.style.display = "none";
                 screen_menu.style.display = "block";
                 screen_setting.style.display = "none";
                 screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
                 break;

        case 2:  screen_snake.style.display = "none";
                 screen_menu.style.display = "none";
                 screen_setting.style.display = "block";
                 screen_gameover.style.display = "none";
                 break;

        case 3: screen_snake.style.display = "none";
                screen_menu.style.display = "none";
                screen_setting.style.display = "none";
                screen_gameover.style.display = "block";
                break;
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.onload = function(){

    canvas = document.getElementById("snake");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Screens
        screen_snake = document.getElementById("snake");
        screen_menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        screen_gameover = document.getElementById("gameover");
        screen_setting = document.getElementById("setting");

        // Buttons
        button_newgame_menu = document.getElementById("newgame_menu");
        button_newgame_setting = document.getElementById("newgame_setting");
        button_newgame_gameover = document.getElementById("newgame_gameover");
        button_setting_menu = document.getElementById("setting_menu");
        button_setting_gameover = document.getElementById("setting_gameover");

        // etc
        ele_score = document.getElementById("score_value");
        speed_setting = document.getElementsByName("speed");
        wall_setting = document.getElementsByName("wall");

    // --------------------

    button_newgame_menu.onclick = function(){newGame();};
    button_newgame_gameover.onclick = function(){newGame();}; 
    button_newgame_setting.onclick = function(){newGame();}; 
    button_setting_menu.onclick = function(){showScreen(2);};
    button_setting_gameover.onclick = function(){showScreen(2)};

    setSnakeSpeed(150);
    setWall(1);

    showScreen("menu");

    // --------------------
    // Settings

        // speed
        for(var i = 0; i < speed_setting.length; i++){
            speed_setting[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < speed_setting.length; i++){
                    if(speed_setting[i].checked){
                        setSnakeSpeed(speed_setting[i].value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // wall
        for(var i = 0; i < wall_setting.length; i++){
            wall_setting[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < wall_setting.length; i++){
                    if(wall_setting[i].checked){
                        setWall(wall_setting[i].value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    document.onkeydown = function(evt){
        if(screen_gameover.style.display == "block"){
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if(evt.keyCode == 32){
                newGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

})();

I use a mini snake games on a client's site, it is created in javascript. When purchasing an item, the customer can play mini games and if he reaches the score it displays a div with a promo code. I cannot capture the score in the first div to display the other div when the score is reached. I did a lot of research but I can't find any solution, I manage to hide the div with the promo code without worry but it is when the score is reached to display it, I arrive there with an input field but this is impossible because anyone can enter the score directly, if someone can help me.

Comment: can you share some of their code ?

Comment: The game is already created and the score increment, it's just hiding and displaying the promotional code at the right time when the score is reached. I added the elements in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solved**

Bravo for uploading your code, check out a working prototype on https://jsfiddle.net/alvinmoyo/jLfwqc6b/3/

What I edited:

```
//1. You need to add a css class to hide the promo code by default. 
//2. I added the function checkScoreSufficiency() which is on my other answer.
//3. Instead of capturing the score from the div (which can be hacked by Inspect- Element tool) capture the score when the snake eats food. (line242)
// NB You can reduce the score on line 168 for faster testing
```

Comment: Super thank you very much for your help, it works fine. The only concern that I meet now is that the game launches automatically when the page is displayed whereas before

Comment: My bad, that was for testing purposes, just remove line 382.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the score with `element.innerText` and convert it to a number using `Number()`.
Remove a `hidden` attribute to unhide the promotional code.

```
if(Number(document.getElementById('score').innerText) >= 500)
    document.getElementById('promotional-code').removeAttribute('hidden');
```

Keep in mind that with this method, a user can still change the score directly or view the promotional code in the source using Inspect Element.

Answer (score 0):

You could have shared some code snippets for a better answer. However, from your description, you can run a function whenever the score increases to check if the player has obtained enough points to see the promo-code

```
function checkScoreSufficiency(currentScore){

    let sufficientScore=100; //assuming you want to display coupon at 100points
    let divWithCoupon= document.getElementById('promotional-code');
    if (currentScore>= suffientScore){
        divWithCoupon.classList.remove('hidden') // negate whatever method you used to hide the coupon here.
    }
}
```

Since you do not want the user to manipulate the score on your game you can store the game score in a text and not an input. Capture the score this way;

```
//put this piece of code where you record score changes or when you are ready to get the score.
let userScore= document.getElementById('score').InnerText
checkScoreSufficiency(userScore);
```

Comment: I put the code entirely for clarity, thanks for your help

Comment: It means that document.getElementById() could not find the id that you referenced. Make sure that you know the actual id of the div containing the score. If your id is let's say 'scoreDiv' put it as document.getElementByID('scoreDiv');

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen your updated code your id is actually 'score_value'. so you say document.getElementByID('score_value').

Comment: Check out my new answer, upvote and accept it as the answer if it satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!---this style will be add if the div-score content be more or equal
    than 500-->
<style>
        .promotional-code-hide{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <div>
        <div id="score">500</div>
        <!--Hide, and when the score is reached it is displayed-->
        <div id="promotional-code" display='none'>RETRO50</div>
    </div>


    <script>
        var divScore = document.querySelector('#score')
        var divPromotionalCode = document.querySelector('#promotional-code')
        if(parseInt(divScore.textContent) < 500 ){
            divPromotionalCode.classList.add("promotional-code-hide")
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, unfortunately I was not successful, I put my code entirely, if it can be more explicit.

Comment: Precisely I would like to do the opposite, that it appears once the 500 exceeds and not that it disappears